# Printf() during read function using readahead() increase the I/Os. why?

Tags: c, linux, samba, smb, buffering

I have a SMB server in Linux (not SAMBA) and in the read request (function) i'm  using the readahead() function.
I'm reading in a loop a 24KB file the client ask to read the file using frame size of 4KB (6 requests in a loop).

The thing is when i'm using the printf() for each read i'm getting 20% more I/Os!!! and i don't understand why.

Here is the code example:

```
typedef struct _MYFile                  /* file descriptor */
{
    FILE*  file;                    /* underlying file handle */
    chat*  fileBuf[24*1024];
    uint64  fileId;                 /* file Id */
    uint64 fileOffset;              /* the file offset */
    uint64 readAHeadOffset;         /* the read a head offset */
    uint64 readAHeadLength;         /* length of the read a head frame */
}MYFile
```

Create the file: (the file is saved in my DB)

```
void create()
{
   MYFile file;

   file.file = fopen(name, "w+");
   file.readAHeadOffset = 0;
   file.readAHeadLength = 0;
   file.fileId = 1;
   updateDB(file)
   setvbuf(file.file, file.fileBuf, _IOFBF, sizeof(file.fileBuf));
}
```

Now i'm getting the read request:

```
void read(uint32 size, uint64 offset, uint64fileId, char* readBuf)
{
    MYFile * file;

    file = getFileFromDB(fileId);
        /* position to the offset */
    if (file->offset != offset)
       lseek(fileno(file->file), (off_t)offset, SEEK_SET);

    if (0 == file->readAHeadLength)
    {
        readahead(file->file, 0, 0, size * 6);

        file->readAHeadLength = params->length * 6;
    }
    //printf("print\n");
    fread(fileno(file->file), readBuf, size);
}
```

So the readahead() called only once.
* with the printf("print\n); i'm getting around 16000 I/Os and without only around 14000.

** It seem that even if i don't use the readahead() the performance goes better.
*** And i have the same issue when i'm adding printf() to the write() function.
Anyone can Enlighten me?

Thanks a head :)

**EDIT 1:**

I am connected to the Linux with putty.exe (ssh:22) and every "printf" a message is sent through the network and the print is shown on my terminal.
So my guess is that the "printf" is making a syscall and makes my message to be sent and not wait to (i think)kernel timeout to be sent.

The question is what "printf" does and how i can mimic it to increase the numbers of I/Os.

**EDIT 2:** (more info)

my server receives requests in one thread and responds in another. I am using thread pools of pthread-s for both receiving and sending. The performance is not that bad, however...

When I am doing the same algorithm in one thread only(MULTITHREAD not defined) so that both recvs and sends are in the same worker thread, my app runs about 10% better.

Strangely, when I am using separate threads(worker and operation) but include printf in any operation, the performance raises **(yes, raises - not declines)** some 20%. My printfs goes over SSH.(*)

(Packet analyses shows some 100 micros of delay of ACKing responses (not separate ACKs). This delay does not happen with the printfs, neither it happens in a single-thread mode. It seems like SSH triggers something in the TCP stack. )

I tried to use the TCP_QUICKACK option after every recv() but the performance goes down!(**)
I am using Centos7. The application is very concurrent - it is SMB server.

The algorithm is as follow:
one thread that get the message with epoll_wait() and then execute the first worker thread, this thread parse the message and launch the operation thread(create/read/write etc.).

**main thread:**

```
static void mainThreadBodySocketTransport(CSTransport * transport)
{
    struct epoll_event e;
    int res;

    while (true)
    {
        void * context = NULL;              /* to pass to thread */
        res = epoll_wait(transport->epoll, &e, 1, (int)*60 * 12 * 1000));
        if (res == 1)
        {
            *context = e.data.ptr;
        }
    /* wrapper to execute the worker thread */
        cmThreadPoolExecute(transport->threadPool, context);
    }
}
```

**worker thread**

```
static void threadBodySocketTransport(void * context)
{
   msgBuffer * message;

   message = parseMSG(context);
   switch (message->cmd)
   {
   case WRITE:
      doWriteOp(message);
   break;
   case READ:
      doReadOp(message);
   break;
   case CREATE:
      doCreateOp(message);
   break;
   }
}

void doWriteOp(msgBuffer * message)
{
#ifdef MULTITHREAD
    /* wrapper to execute the worker thread */
    cmThreadPoolExecute(threadPoolWrite, (void *)message);
#else
    /* write to file */
    threadBodyWrite(message);
#endif
}
```

**operation thread**

```
static void threadBodyWrite(void * context)
{
   msgBuffer * message = (msgBuffer *)context;
   int fd;

   .
   .(get the fd)
   .
   /* printf("w\n");*/
   write(fd, message->write.data , message->write.len);
   sendResponse(message->cmd, true);
}
```

**pthread create**

```
void threadStart(SYThread *taskIdPtr, void (*startpoint)(void), NQ_BOOL background)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(taskIdPtr, &attr, (void * (*)(void *))startpoint, NULL)
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}
```

Maybe i need to use different thread attribute??

Please HELP.

Thanks.